# how to stretch a uiview within a uiview in interface builder on orientation change?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, autolayout, autoresize

In Interface Builder I have my main UIView however inside of this I have another UIView which acts as a header (different colour background and contains centered text whereas the main UIView behind and seen below the header contains other centered text).

The app was originally built for portrait mode. Now that I have allowed landscape mode, when I rotate the device, all the text auto resizes to remain in the center of the screen, but the header view remains the same width and locked to the left of the screen so I have a lot of trailing space to the right of it as it doesnt go all the way to the other side of the screen.

After looking for a solution I still haven't found one which fixes the problem so how do I set this UIView to stretch automatically on orientation change like all the text labels?

Comment: I couldn't quiet follow but since one object is behaving as expected and the other is not, why not use the same autoresizing mask for both of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple using auto layout. Give that view a constraint to the left, right, and top of its superview, and no fixed width. You can give it a fixed height if that's what you want, or give it a height that's proportional to the height of the screen (this would have to be done in code) if you want it to be shorter in landscape.